# What does "[arête]" mean, inside of a quote?

Tags: grammar, quotations

My copy of [Xenophon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polity_of_the_Lacedaemonians) has a sentence that looks like this:

> ...because she alone makes the development of moral excellence [*arête*] a public duty.

(italics are in the quote itself; "she" refers to Sparta)

What does [arête] mean here? Online, I could only find information about a certain type of rock formation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arete the accent over the e may be an error (at least in English)

Comment: [*If Aristotle is right that part of human flourishing and authentic happiness includes acting in accord with moral excellence (**arête** in Greek, **virtus** in Latin)...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ar%C3%AAte+in+Greek%2C+virtus+in+Latin%22)

Comment: ...but I'm not sure obscure ancient Greek words are on topic here. Even the full OED doesn't list this meaning- it's only got Old French **arête** (etymologically unrelated) with the well-known sense *a sharp ascending ridge or ‘edge’ of a mountain.* Besides which, OP's cited context actually *specifies* the meaning anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English, but a foreign-language word cited in an English text in a way identical to how it would be cited in most other languages.

Comment: @AllInOne The circumflex itself is not an error, but it’s position is: the Greek is _ἀρετή_, which, by the scheme used, should be _aretê_, with the circumflex over the second e, not the first.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: When I posted my comments above, I hedged a bit because the fact of a "word" not being in the full OED doesn't *necessarily* mean it's not in use. But on second thoughts that's mainly relevant to *newer* usages - this one has presumably been at least *potentially* around for millennia, so if the OED never thought it was worth including, I'm happy to say it ain't English.

Comment: ...note that the relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arete) entry doesn't use any accents. But it does seem pretty obvious the one cited here is completely wrong, since it refers to a totally unrelated word.

Comment: _Arrêt_ would have at least been more amusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This addition in square brackets is not supposed to be part of the running text; it is a **note to inform the reader** that the term *moral excellence* was chosen by the translator to represent the Greek word ἀρετή. The purpose of such a note is to allow those who know some Greek to understand the possible nuances present in the Greek word that might be lost in translation. *Arête* is an (incorrect) translitteration of the Greek word into Latin letters (it should be *aretê*).

It could be argued that this question is about the practice of translators; as such, it is neither about the Greek word, nor about the meaning of an English word per se; but it is about an important aspect of the profession of translators, which is probably part of the curriculum of most students of English literature. As such, it might be considered on topic for this website.

On the other hand, the reading of texts written in English, such as this one, and the correct interpretation of conventions used in many English texts of the same genre, might be considered part of the English language and its usage, and hence also on topic.

P.S. The spelling error may be caused by confusion with the unrelated geographical term *arête*, which is originally French but also used in English.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments on your question, *arête* is a misspelling of [*arete*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Arete&oldid=844427431), meaning “excellence of any kind”, particularly moral excellence (as used in your example). When transliterated directly from the Greek *ἀρετή*, it is also spelled [*aretê*](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=aret%C3%AA&oldid=40600986) or [*areté*](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=aret%C3%A9&oldid=40132285). Thus, the circumflex is not an error, but is misplaced. In your example, *arete* is used only as a synonym for *moral excellence*.